# audioplayers not working when app in background flutter

Tags: flutter-audioplayers, flutter-workmanager

Is the audioplayers plugin meant to work when app is in background?

I am calling this line `await player.play(AssetSource(audioFilePlath));` when app is in background and no sound is played.
The same code works when app is visible.
I have looked up the issues page on github where this issue has been mentioned already but with no satisfactory response.